# location.reload event triggers the button click events after reload page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a simple requirement. Need to refresh a parent page from child window once it closes. I am opening a child window from a btnsearch_Click, the code is:

```
sclientScript="open_GG9080('?name="&shareName&"&No=1')"
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "event","<script type='text/javascript'>"&sclientScript&"</script>");
```

and javascript method in parent page is:

```
function open_GG9080() {
        window.open("Page2.aspx", "Shan", "width=200,height=200,scrollbars=no");
    }
```

and in child page i have

```
function refreshAndClose() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
        self.close();
    }
```

and calling this in

Now its working as expected it calls the page load event of parent window when I close the child window but its also going intto the button click event (the button click event through which i called the child window) and executes the javascript method again. So again Child window appears and this goes recursively.
How to avoid this ? I am nbew to asp.net. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to share the entire button click function from the parent page that opens the child window?

Comment: yes, i edited my post with the entire button click function from the parent page that opens the child window.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are opening the child window from a button click then does the script to do that need to be registered as a startup script? As it is the startup script it means it is called each time the page is loaded/reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to avoid triggering the button click events after reload page.

I post in here for someone need:

In child page :

- set a session :

```
session("reload")="1"
```

In `btnSearch_click` on parent page :

```
if session("reload") = "1" then
    exit sub
else
    //do something
end if
```

thank you and good luck